# Java web development using Eclipse - Tutorial

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I need some step by step tutorials/documents on developing Java web applications using Eclipse/apache.

appreciate directions/help.

Comment: what do you mean by "eclipse/apache"?

Comment: Eclipse is the IDE for J2EE development.

Apache is the application server for running java programs

Comment: Apache is a web server; I think he wants Tomcat or some other servlet/JSP engine.  My direction would be to get Tomcat and forget about the Apache web server.

Comment: i think i have tomcat installed. I was referring to tomcat in the name of apache. my understanding was Apache tomcat is a single application server. Pls advise if my assumption is incorrect.

Comment: You need Tomcat, the servlet/JSP engine from the Apache foundation.  The URL is http://tomcat.apache.org.  If that's what you have, then you've got the right thing.

Comment: +1 cause its a good beginner question with some nice answers

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you read a book instead:

This is probably the simplest way to get started. It really helped me with getting a grasp on how the directory structure and web.xml go together and make a web app. Eclipse is only a partner in your development, you really need to understand the underlying infrastructure no matter what framework you are using, and this book gives you a solid start.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There are some video tutorials available at http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/

The first tutorial begins with the absolute basics of setting up a workspace and getting started.  It also shows the Welcome screen available under the help menu which has links to an overview, samples, and tutorials

Comment: these are a bit old: "The tutorials use Eclipse version 3.3 (Europa), released June 2007."

Comment: I've just watched the first two (I'm running 3.7.2) and nothing they have talked about has been outdated so far. Very helpful for those that want an intro to the features of the Eclipse workspace (irrespective of what you're doing with it). It also has some of the best tutorial intro music ever made (!).

Answer (score 2):

As you've already installed Apache Tomcat. I assume you've not installed Java EE tools for Eclipse. If not, then First download Eclipse Java EE tools from Help > Software Updates > Available Software > Java EE developer Tools.

**First way :** is using Tomcat plugin with eclipse,for that you've to check [this tutorial](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html)

**Second way:** If the Tomcat Plugin is not working with you then other alternative as follow Click on Click Window in menu> Preferences then click **Server** pane. Open Runtime Requirement pane. Add path for the tomcat directory. Click Ok. You're done with the settings.

Now you can create new projects from File >New >Projects. And start building servlets/jsp projects. Try learning from good books like "Head first: Servlets & JSP".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you first start Eclipse there is a screen with tutorials right in the program. They are also accessible from the Help menu

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of that old joke:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Sounds like you have several things that you don't know: Eclipse, Tomcat, Java EE development, maybe JSPs, JSTL, WAR files, the list goes on.

My advice would be to strip things down to the bare bones and decompose the problem a bit.

Start by doing a simple servlet/JSP app talking to a database, without using Eclipse.  See if you can compile on the command line, create the WAR file, package it properly, and deploy it on Tomcat.

If you can manage that, then work Eclipse into the mix.  Don't worry about running Tomcat inside Eclipse at first.  You can go back and forth until the IDE is comfortable.

But you're asking a lot when you say you'd like step by step instructions.  You're tackling a very big problem.

Answer (score 0):

DZone REFCARZ might be helpful, there's one for eclipse:
[Getting Started with Eclipse](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-eclipse)